# How to prevent button from dropdown menu from wrapping?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a search form in a dropdown menu. I tried different css rules but failed to prevent the button from wrapping into the next line. Below is my original HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
    <form id="navbar-search" role="search" action="/discover" method="post">
        <input class="form-control" type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Search">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"/>
            </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is what it looked like:

[image: button-wrapped]

I want the button to be placed beside the input form like this:

[image: button-not-wrapped]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show a JSFiddle or the CSS you have applied.

Comment: try setting both the search box and the button to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @SunnyRGupta, I have tried wrapping the button with `<div style="display:table-cell;width:1%">` as seen here: http://www.bootply.com/79128

Comment: @Tinfoilboy, I just tried your suggestion but the button is still below the search box. The button by the way have already the property of `display: inline-block` defined in its .btn class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also the [Bootstrap input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

You can tighten the space by changing the right padding of the `.search-me form`

[image]

**DEMO: https://jsbin.com/mosiwi/1/edit?html,css,output**

**CSS**

```
.search-me form {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 55px 10px 10px;
}
.search-me .btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu-300 {
    min-width: 300px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-300" role="menu">
      <li class="search-me">
         <form id="navbar-search" role="search" action="/discover" method="post">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Search">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"/>
            </button>
         </form>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vvj1qorj/

Here is a quick hack:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
                    <form id="navbar-search" role="search" action="/discover" method="post" class="btn-group  "> 
                        <div class="btn-group input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary pull-right" title="Search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```